# How to Quickly Update Mongo Documents String Fields with Complex Functions

Tags: performance, mongodb

What is the fastest way to update documents in a Mongo database with complex functions, let's say a string search / replace or a `sqrt` calculation?

Since such operations are missing, e.g. a `$replace`, it is not possible with `update` (which would probably be the fastest, since on my test collection it only takes about 50 ms to set a field on some 100k objects).

When I simply iterate over all documents it takes about 45 seconds. It gets a little faster when I limit my query to the fields I'm using during the update.

This time of course grow larger on larger collections, therefore the question whether there is a faster way than iterating over the collection (e.g. via a map reduce job?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No :) Without native support for such functionality you'll be stuck with a read->modify->write approach. That said if you can write a field to 100k objects on a machine that manages that in 50ms that process shouldn't take anywhere near 45 seconds if you have to read, modify and write those same documents. Are you sure the bottleneck is the database rather than the machine that is running that pass? Are you sure you're batching appropriately and not do an update per document?

Comment: As I feared. Thanks for the batching tip, I forgot that. It improves the performance to 15 seconds (batching reads).

Comment: Good. Note that you can do batch updates as well through large $in clauses.